# English version of the "Spécialité Mathématiques" French baccalaureate course (for a Ukrainian refugee)?

Tags: curriculum

The highschool where I'm teaching welcomes a Ukrainian refugee who is in "classe Terminale" (ultimate highschool grade in France).

The math teacher who has this student in charge is not that fluent in English, but the student speaks English very correctly.

This is why we are looking for online resources in English that correspond to the program of the subject called "Spécialité Mathématiques".

The only thing I've found so far is a course by Paul Milan (Paris Highschool For Adults), but the course deals with an older program (2015) : https://www.lyceedadultes.fr/sitepedagogique/pages/mathTermS_english.html

Do you know of any resource that could be helpful?

If not courses devoted to the French baccalaureate program, maybe courses related to International Baccalaureate's Mathematics, hoping the two programs overlap.

Comment: Can you perhaps post a link to the French resources that correspond to Specialite mathematiques? Without knowing what content you are looking for (even if the only resources you have are French) it is hard to answer this question.

Comment: For example, is this list of subjects complete? Is there an official resource with a list of subjects at some website? 

https://www.studyrama.com/formations/diplomes/bac/les-programmes-et-attendus-des-12-specialites/bac-2021-tout-savoir-sur-la-specialite-mathematiques-106372